# Add custom formulas to Google sheets using Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to calculate to cells but not working. This is my code :

```
function total() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
     var cell = sheet.getRange("A3");
     var calculate = cell.setFormula("=SUM(A1+A2)");

     return calculate

 }
```

My cell is A1 AND A2 I want to put result in cell A3 by add "=total()".

not working but if run from script it work.
I want to put =total() in cell A3 and work without see my formula in sheet.
I wand to send copy of my sheet to people and he can read and edit it.
I don't need people to see my formulas.
or any another way to hide my formulas from people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the result in the script:

```js
function total() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var values = sheet.getRange("A1:A2").getValues();
  var value = values[0][0] + values[1][0];
  return value;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can

1. Calculate normally with formulas in another spreadsheet
2. Use `IMPORTRANGE` to import the data from that spreadsheet such that only values but not formulas are display in the cells

However, he cannot make changes to the range directly.

He need to first copy and paste by values.

Comment: Thanks Bro it's work but why about multi range I try this but not working `getRange("A1:A1000").getValues()` `values[0][0] + values[1000][0];` this method not working

Comment: For `A1:A1000`, the last value is `values[999][0]`. Also, you are only adding 2 values. To get the summation, try `var value = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b[0], 0);`

Comment: This method work but the problem if I jump one cell and write to next cell I see error `#NUM!` , cab I do this without select specific sheet and range

Comment: I cannot get what you mean. How can you calculate without specifying sheet and range?

Comment: Like that `function divideByTwoAddOne(x){return x/2 }`,

Comment: What is your question? You can do any calculation in the function.

Comment: I do same that with sum cell beside another cell like that in sheet `=total(B4,C4)` by `function total(x,y){return x+y }` in app script, this method work great, how can I do same that with multi cell example sum all these cell A1:A100

Comment: Read [Arguments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Your custom formula is returning the return value of the function [Range.setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula), which [is a Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#return_149). And you want a number. For this you need the *values* of both cells "A1"and "A2".

Furthermore, if you are using this custom formula to set a *value* in cell "A3" and not a *formula* then you can just have the custom formula return the value.

### Example:

```js
function total() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var values = sheet.getRange("A1:A2").getValues();
  var value = values[0][0] + values[1][0];
  return value;
}
```